# Failed to introspect Class [com.expedia.www.metrics.MetricsConfiguration]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I was trying to upgrade the spring boot (new version : 2.6.6) and spring (new version : 5.3.18) versions of an application and encountered the below error.

*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.expedia.www.metrics.MetricsConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd]*

With the below previous versions it was working as expected.
Spring boot - 2.0.9.RELEASE
Spring - 5.0.13.RELEASE

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on com.expedia.www.metrics.MetricsConfiguration.monitoringAgent
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at com.expedia.www.eps.auxiliary.Starter.main(Starter.java:51) [classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.expedia.www.metrics.MetricsConfiguration] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/codahale/metrics/JmxReporter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:361) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:418) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:765) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:764) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:674) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1670) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:250) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:243) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:233) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:181) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:119) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    ... 15 more
```

Here is my pom.xml snippet

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>*************</artifactId>
    <groupId>************</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>**************</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Service Sample</description>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.jdk.version>${java.version}</project.jdk.version>
        <project.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <start-class>com.expedia.www.eps.auxiliary.Starter</start-class>

        <!-- Following properties are for release. -->
        <buildType>sandbox</buildType>
        <buildNumber>0</buildNumber>
        <buildBranch>local</buildBranch>
        <changeNumber>local</changeNumber>
        <depotInfo>none</depotInfo>
        <buildTime>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTime>

        <spring-boot.version>2.6.6</spring-boot.version>
        <spring.version>5.3.18</spring.version>
        <aws.version>1.10.22</aws.version>
        <metrics-servlet.version>3.1.2</metrics-servlet.version>
        <platform-monitoring.version>1.2.0</platform-monitoring.version>
        <platform-isactive.version>1.1.18</platform-isactive.version>
        <platform-build-tools.version>0.1.49</platform-build-tools.version>
        <fasterxml.jackson.version>2.13.2</fasterxml.jackson.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>

        <findbugs-maven-plugin.version>3.0.4</findbugs-maven-plugin.version>
        <findbugs.include.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/include.xml</findbugs.include.filter.location>
        <findbugs.exclude.filter.location>buildtools/findbugs/exclude.xml</findbugs.exclude.filter.location>
        <maven-pmd-plugin.version>3.5</maven-pmd-plugin.version>
        <pmd.version>5.3.2</pmd.version>
        <pmd.ruleset.location>${project.basedir}/buildtools/ruleset.xml</pmd.ruleset.location>
        <pmd.skip>false</pmd.skip>

        <!-- spring boot -->
        <debug.port>5000</debug.port>
        <run.jvmArguments>-Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dapplication.home=. -Dapplication.name=${project.name}
            -Dapplication.environment=dev -Dproject.name=${project.name} -Xdebug
            -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${debug.port}
        </run.jvmArguments>

        <error-inspector.version>0.1.9</error-inspector.version>
        <platform-diagnostics.version>1.1.5</platform-diagnostics.version>

        <!-- Jacoco code coverage -->
        <sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.itReportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
        <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
        <sonar.exclusions>**/*HttpConfiguration.java</sonar.exclusions>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--
                explicit override for the log4j2 vulnerability;
                this can be removed once newer spring boot version released with the fix;
                this HAS TO be defined before the default spring boot dependencies.
            -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-transit</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-serialization</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www</groupId>
            <artifactId>offerservice-sdk-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.88-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-configuration-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-isactive</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-isactive.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-monitoring</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-monitoring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <!--<exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>-->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${metrics-servlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www</groupId>
            <artifactId>springboot-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ajar</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-spring-mvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-diagnostics</artifactId>
            <version>${platform-diagnostics.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mikesamuel</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-partner</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-filters</artifactId>
            <version>3.20</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-service-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.30.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>${aws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia.ews</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>expedia</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.expedia.e3.platform.messaging.core</artifactId>
            <version>[1.0,)</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-ensconce</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-ensconce-vault</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.expedia.www.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-ensconce-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <message>.

                                        *** ERROR: Detected Maven version ${maven.version}, We need Maven 3.0.3 or
                                        higher ***

                                        .
                                    </message>
                                    <version>[3.0.3,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <message>.

                                        *** ERROR: Detected JDK version ${java.version}, We need JDK
                                        ${project.jdk.version} or higher ***

                                        .
                                    </message>
                                    <version>${project.jdk.version}</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```